# Is there way to use plain Ant to remote deploy to Websphere 6.1 without having WAS or RAD locally?

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, websphere

There are quite a few questions here about using ant to deploy to websphere but they all use ws_ant.bat or wsadmin ...

I want to automatically deploy to a remote Websphere 6.1 server from a build server (running Atlassian Bamboo) which doens't have WAS or RAD deployed. Is this even possible? I've tried setting up the ant tasks but I'm running into problems getting the wsInstallApp task to execute.

I've got com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar on the classpath so the task starts executing but it reports that it is unable to determine WAS Home directory (even though the wasHome attribute is optional).

Has anybody succeeded in deploying to a remote WAS 6.1 server this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the admin thinclient, but that is only available in WebSphere Application Server 7.0 and later.  The only supported option for 6.1 and earlier is to install the product (client or server) on your build machine.